# Stop Watching A Directory for Changes (cleanup)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, nio

I implemented a directory watcher following the java tutorial: https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/watching_a_directory_for_changes

I have it on a separate thread that updates a JList. Everything seems to be working fine, what I wanted to know is: Do I need to do some type of cleanup somewhere and what would be the best way to do so if that's the case. Because that thread is basically waiting the whole time just in case something happens, after that it goes back to waiting for the next change.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If it's a daemon thread, probably not.  If you do get some problem, you could stop it by means of some 'terminateAndExit' boolean flag that is always checked when the blocking call returns.  To make it return after settting the flag, just create some temp file, then delete it again.

Comment: unrelated: you are doing the JList update on the EDT, do you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should close the WatchService.

http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/WatchService.html#close()

Obviously, if you are going to watch the same path(s) for the duration of your program, you can just exit and rely on OS to clean up.